# Create a file from Shell script Variable

Tags: shell

I am trying to create a file from a shell script variable (.sh file ext)

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGNAME=`date +"error/postgresql.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H00.csv"`

echo Log File Name is: ${LOGNAME}

echo > ${LOGNAME}

aws rds download-db-log-file-portion --db-instance-identifier randomDBname --log-file-name ${LOGNAME} --starting-token 0 --output -n text > ${LOGNAME} --profile aws

sleep 20
```

I receive this error:

```
error/postgresql.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H00.csv: No such file or directory
```

I have tried the following and all have the same error:

```
echo >> ${LOGNAME}
echo -n >> ${LOGNAME}
echo "Starting Log" > ${LOGNAME}
```

The echo log file name works fine and prints the log file name without issue. Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, the file is created for me.

Comment: Is this the complete script? Any other commands that assume the file exists before the `echo > ${LOGNAME}` line?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I updated the OP to reflect exactly what I am trying to do, I couldn't get it to work with the AWS CLI commands as well and that's what I originally posted.

Comment: Found it, its the / in ```error/postgresql```, I think its looking for a folder named error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGNAME=`date +"error/postgresql.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H00.csv"`
FILENAME=`date +"error-postgresql.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H00.csv"`

echo Log File Name is: ${LOGNAME}

aws rds download-db-log-file-portion --db-instance-identifier randomDBname --log-file-name ${LOGNAME} --starting-token 0 --output csv > ${FILENAME} --profile aws
```

Found the issue, it was the `/` in `error/postgresql`.